# Is there a way in Django to combine two queries of a single model with different parameters?

Tags: python, django, mariadb

I'd like to be able to display a table with a stores current value, as well as the value from last year. Right now I query all the stores, and then for each store I loop through and get the value from the comparison date and time. But this ends up taking 60+ queries.

Here are my models. All of the data lives in the ShowroomData model

```
class Stores(models.Model):
    storeid = models.IntegerField(default=0, primary_key=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class ShowroomData(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Stores, db_column="storeid", default=0, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(db_index = True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    time = models.IntegerField()  # Field name made lowercase.
    sales = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)  # Field name made lowercase.
    tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

My views.py

```
    for store in current_data:
        comparison_data = ShowroomData.objects.filter(store=self.store, date=comparison_date, time=self.time)
        if comparison_data:
            for record in comparison_data:
                store.compare_amount = record.sales + record.tax
```

I'd like to be able to store all of these in one query set, and then loop over it in the templates instead of having to loop through in the beginning to re append the query. If at all possible to have the data from the second query in a seperate field in the query set? Thank you!

Comment: sounds like you might be looking for `.annotate` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate

Comment: you can use the `F` object: `ShowroomData.objects.filter(store=self.store, date=comparison_date, time=self.time).annotate(compare_amount=F('sales')+F('tax'))`, see also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters

Comment: I will try this, thank you for the info!

Comment: How do i get this to fill the compare_amount with data from a year ago? I would like all the data from current and the amount from last year to be within one query set.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is is possible with [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/).

**[annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate)** is used to create per-object summaries, while the
**[F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters)** object, in your case, is used to sum two fields.

```
ShowroomData.objects.annotate(compare_amount=F('sales')+F('tax')).filter(store=self.store, date=comparison_date, time=self.time))
```

Comment: So if I wanted the table to end up saying:

StoreID - Sales - Time - Amount From last year

This would be the best approach?

Comment: I personally think that this is the best approach. Is fast (much faster than using a for loop to create compare_amount field) and readable.